# Fixed INNER header and footer - not among the answered Q's

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As you can see the inner-header and inner-footer div scroll down along the are that contains the select list.

How do I make that area scrolls down and having the inner-header/footer fixed into the content?

I hope my question is clear enough. Thank you

```css
  * {outline: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        html, body, form { height: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        body {line-height: 1.6; padding-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;}
        footer {background-color: #212934;padding: 10px 0;width: 100%;position: fixed;height: 50px;bottom: 0px !important;}
        .the-box {height: 100%; min-height: 600px;padding: 0px;background: #fff; margin: 0px 0 !important; margin-bottom: 50px !important; }
        .inner-heder {background: #000;color: #fff;}
        .inner-footer {background: #ccc;color: #fff }
```

```html
    <!-- Latest Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="inner-heder">
                <div class="static-top">
                    Inner-heder content here
                </div>
                <div class="scroll-only-me">
                <select id="testlist" size="60" style="width: 100%;">
                    <option value="0">Please select</option>
                    <option value="1">Item #1</option>
                    <option value="2">Item #2</option>
                    <option value="3">Item #3</option>
                    <option value="4">Item #4</option>
                    <option value="5">Item #5</option>
                    <option value="6">Item #6</option>
                    <option value="7">Item #7</option>
                    <option value="8">Item #8</option>
                    <option value="9">Item #9</option>
                    <option value="10">Item #10</option>
                    <option value="11">Item #11</option>
                    <option value="12">Item #12</option>
                    <option value="13">Item #13</option>
                    <option value="14">Item #14</option>
                    <option value="15">Item #15</option>
                    <option value="16">Item #16</option>
                    <option value="17">Item #17</option>
                    <option value="18">Item #18</option>
                    <option value="19">Item #19</option>
                    <option value="20">Item #20</option>
                    <option value="21">Item #21</option>
                    <option value="22">Item #22</option>
                    <option value="23">Item #23</option>
                    <option value="24">Item #24</option>
                    <option value="25">Item #25</option>
                    <option value="26">Item #26</option>
                    <option value="27">Item #27</option>
                    <option value="28">Item #28</option>
                    <option value="29">Item #29</option>
                    <option value="30">Item #30</option>
                    <option value="31">Item #31</option>
                    <option value="32">Item #32</option>
                    <option value="33">Item #33</option>
                    <option value="34">Item #34</option>
                    <option value="35">Item #35</option>
                    <option value="36">Item #36</option>
                    <option value="37">Item #37</option>
                    <option value="38">Item #38</option>
                    <option value="39">Item #39</option>
                    <option value="40">Item #40</option>
                    <option value="41">Item #41</option>
                    <option value="42">Item #42</option>
                    <option value="43">Item #43</option>
                    <option value="44">Item #44</option>
                    <option value="45">Item #45</option>
                    <option value="46">Item #46</option>
                    <option value="47">Item #47</option>
                    <option value="48">Item #48</option>
                    <option value="49">Item #49</option>
                    <option value="50">Item #50</option>
                    <option value="51">Item #51</option>
                    <option value="52">Item #52</option>
                    <option value="53">Item #53</option>
                    <option value="54">Item #54</option>
                    <option value="55">Item #55</option>
                    <option value="56">Item #56</option>
                    <option value="57">Item #57</option>
                    <option value="58">Item #58</option>
                    <option value="59">Item #59</option>
                    <option value="60">Item #60</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="inner-footer">
                    Inner-footer content here
                </div> <!-- /.inner-footer -->
            </div> <!-- /.the-box -->
        </div> <!-- /.container -->

        <footer class="hidden-xs" style="width: 100%;position: fixed;height: 50px;bottom:0px !important;">
            <p>Footer text here</p>
        </footer>
    </form>
```

Comment: I don't understand "which should be the only scrollable area being stretched over the rest of the space"

Comment: Just the left space between the inner header and footer. The area where the select control is placed. Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please make it more clear. Thank you

Comment: I still didn't understand. Edit the question itself, if you will

Comment: An example(UI Screenshot) of what you were trying to achieve would help.

Comment: I did. Meaning the only scrollable (movable) div should be the one with the class scroll-me-only and it should fill the whole remaining space between the inner header and footer. Thank you guys

Comment: Do you want both headers and the footer to be visible at all times

Comment: Both divs are scrollable

Comment: Exactly as now the inner ones move and get hidden if you scroll down the page. Thank you

Comment: Screenshots: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2dtJO.png
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbt8F.png
[3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GufQF.png

Comment: Hi Elizabeth. After reading your question, I have zero idea what you are wanting, what you have done, and what the problem is, because you have almost no description before throwing out a wall of code. Adding some screenshots and or sketches of desired behavior would really help people out. I see you added some in comments, but most people aren't going to look through the comments. Edit them into your question, expand upon it, and you'll get more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 * {
        outline: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body,
    form {
        height: 100% !important;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
        line-height: 1.6;
        padding-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    footer {
        background-color: #212934;
        width: 100%;
        flex: 0;
        min-height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .the-box {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 600px;
        padding: 0px
        background: #fff;
        margin: 0px 0 !important;
        margin-bottom: 50px !important;
    }
    
    #form1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .navbar {
        flex: 0;
        min-height: 50px;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        margin-bottom:0 !important;
    }
    
    .inner-heder {
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .inner-container {
        flex: 1;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .static-top{
     flex: 0;
     min-height: 20px;
    }
    #testlist {
        color: #000;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .inner-footer {
        background: #ccc;
        color: #fff;
        flex: 0;
        min-height: 24px;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Latest Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
        <div class="container inner-container">
            <div class="inner-heder">
                <div class="static-top">
                    Inner-heder content here
                </div>
                <select id="testlist" size="60">
                    <option value="0">Please select</option>
                    <option value="1">Item #1</option>
                    <option value="2">Item #2</option>
                    <option value="3">Item #3</option>
                    <option value="4">Item #4</option>
                    <option value="5">Item #5</option>
                    <option value="6">Item #6</option>
                    <option value="7">Item #7</option>
                    <option value="8">Item #8</option>
                    <option value="9">Item #9</option>
                    <option value="10">Item #10</option>
                    <option value="11">Item #11</option>
                    <option value="12">Item #12</option>
                    <option value="13">Item #13</option>
                    <option value="14">Item #14</option>
                    <option value="15">Item #15</option>
                    <option value="16">Item #16</option>
                    <option value="17">Item #17</option>
                    <option value="18">Item #18</option>
                    <option value="19">Item #19</option>
                    <option value="20">Item #20</option>
                    <option value="21">Item #21</option>
                    <option value="22">Item #22</option>
                    <option value="23">Item #23</option>
                    <option value="24">Item #24</option>
                    <option value="25">Item #25</option>
                    <option value="26">Item #26</option>
                    <option value="27">Item #27</option>
                    <option value="28">Item #28</option>
                    <option value="29">Item #29</option>
                    <option value="30">Item #30</option>
                    <option value="31">Item #31</option>
                    <option value="32">Item #32</option>
                    <option value="33">Item #33</option>
                    <option value="34">Item #34</option>
                    <option value="35">Item #35</option>
                    <option value="36">Item #36</option>
                    <option value="37">Item #37</option>
                    <option value="38">Item #38</option>
                    <option value="39">Item #39</option>
                    <option value="40">Item #40</option>
                    <option value="41">Item #41</option>
                    <option value="42">Item #42</option>
                    <option value="43">Item #43</option>
                    <option value="44">Item #44</option>
                    <option value="45">Item #45</option>
                    <option value="46">Item #46</option>
                    <option value="47">Item #47</option>
                    <option value="48">Item #48</option>
                    <option value="49">Item #49</option>
                    <option value="50">Item #50</option>
                    <option value="51">Item #51</option>
                    <option value="52">Item #52</option>
                    <option value="53">Item #53</option>
                    <option value="54">Item #54</option>
                    <option value="55">Item #55</option>
                    <option value="56">Item #56</option>
                    <option value="57">Item #57</option>
                    <option value="58">Item #58</option>
                    <option value="59">Item #59</option>
                    <option value="60">Item #60</option>
                </select>
                <div class="inner-footer">
                    Inner-footer content here
                </div>
                <!-- /.inner-footer -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.the-box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
        <footer class="hidden-xs">
            Footer text here
        </footer>
    </form>
```

Comment: [![issue #1][1]][1]
[![issue #2][2]][2]
[![what i need][3]][3]

[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2dtJO.png
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbt8F.png
[3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GufQF.png

Comment: It works fine only in desktop mode as soon as you resize the browser to extra small the content width gets super small ... i see not code for that though. Any ideas?

Comment: It has something to do with the flex as i see it shrinks the width to 191px when you enter extra small mode. Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: Your Issue 1 & 2 is already fixed in my code and I also check in chrome and mozila with resizing browser window and it is working fine in each resolution. About extra small width like 191px, you need to apply media query and set your inner content width to 100% or may be need to remove margin or padding,

Comment: Indeed. Btw would you like to help me to realize how do i put the testlist into container named inner-body e.g. <div class="inner-body"><select etc. What i need to change in order to make it working fine?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for fixed header and fixed footer with scrollable content like this demo.

**I have updated my answer please check it once.**

**Demo here:**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner_header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #2bde73;  
}
.inner_footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: #2bde73;
}
.content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.select {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    border-color: #080808;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation
        </span>
        <span class="icon-bar">
        </span>
        <span class="icon-bar">
        </span>
        <span class="icon-bar">
        </span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">About
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Services
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav> 
<div class="content">
  <select id="testlist" class="select" size="60">
    <option value="0">Please select
    </option>
    <option value="1">Item #1
    </option>
    <option value="2">Item #2
    </option>
    <option value="3">Item #3
    </option>
    <option value="4">Item #4
    </option>
    <option value="5">Item #5
    </option>
    <option value="6">Item #6
    </option>
    <option value="7">Item #7
    </option>
    <option value="8">Item #8
    </option>
    <option value="9">Item #9
    </option>
    <option value="10">Item #10
    </option>
    <option value="11">Item #11
    </option>
    <option value="12">Item #12
    </option>
    <option value="13">Item #13
    </option>
    <option value="14">Item #14
    </option>
    <option value="15">Item #15
    </option>
    <option value="16">Item #16
    </option>
    <option value="17">Item #17
    </option>
    <option value="18">Item #18
    </option>
    <option value="19">Item #19
    </option>
    <option value="20">Item #20
    </option>
    <option value="21">Item #21
    </option>
    <option value="22">Item #22
    </option>
    <option value="23">Item #23
    </option>
    <option value="24">Item #24
    </option>
    <option value="25">Item #25
    </option>
    <option value="26">Item #26
    </option>
    <option value="27">Item #27
    </option>
    <option value="28">Item #28
    </option>
    <option value="29">Item #29
    </option>
    <option value="30">Item #30
    </option>
    <option value="31">Item #31
    </option>
    <option value="32">Item #32
    </option>
    <option value="33">Item #33
    </option>
    <option value="34">Item #34
    </option>
    <option value="35">Item #35
    </option>
    <option value="36">Item #36
    </option>
    <option value="37">Item #37
    </option>
    <option value="38">Item #38
    </option>
    <option value="39">Item #39
    </option>
    <option value="40">Item #40
    </option>
    <option value="41">Item #41
    </option>
    <option value="42">Item #42
    </option>
    <option value="43">Item #43
    </option>
    <option value="44">Item #44
    </option>
    <option value="45">Item #45
    </option>
    <option value="46">Item #46
    </option>
    <option value="47">Item #47
    </option>
    <option value="48">Item #48
    </option>
    <option value="49">Item #49
    </option>
    <option value="50">Item #50
    </option>
    <option value="51">Item #51
    </option>
    <option value="52">Item #52
    </option>
    <option value="53">Item #53
    </option>
    <option value="54">Item #54
    </option>
    <option value="55">Item #55
    </option>
    <option value="56">Item #56
    </option>
    <option value="57">Item #57
    </option>
    <option value="58">Item #58
    </option>
  </select>                
</div>
<div class="inner_header">Inner Header Section</div>
<div class="inner_footer">Inner Footer Section</div>
<div class="footer">Copyright © Test 2016</div>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the images: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2dtJO.png
[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbt8F.png
[3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GufQF.png

Comment: Thank you but I am having the standard nav and footer too. Could you PLEASE add those too and make it working along your green ones? Will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have added standard nav in my demo you check it once. I need add one more footer area for it.

Comment: This is so soo close. Please add the footer for me. Thank you so much

Comment: Actually, I just realized that you have 100% wide content which is not what i need. I need it to be flexible and to inherit the width from the bootstrap.css

Comment: No worries, you add the bootstrap class here.
<select id="testlist" class="select BootStrap-className" size="60">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118324/discussion-between-sayed-rafeeq-and-elizabeth-dimova).

Comment: Any chances to provide an example for non-absolute positioned elements? Thank you

Comment: May I know do you want space around both sides of select drop-drowns? instead of full width.

Comment: No space. i want it to be spread all over the content (which is left). Thx